# Alternatives for "student body"

Tags: synonyms

The term student body is used to describe the collective students attending a school.

> Of the student body, more than half went to get jobs in business and industry.

But I feel that *body* can have connotations of being dead and sounds morbid.

> The student body was found in a ditch.

Is there an alternative for student body without any bodies?

Comment: I can think of no situation where *student body* couldn't be simply replaced with *students*. Is there something wrong with *Of the students, more than half went to get jobs in business and industry*?

Comment: @JasonBassford Yes. The term *student body* is essentially American. You rarely hear it used in Britain - where we would just say "the students", or "the students of the University"

Comment: I suppose you could use the term "student enrollment," as in "Of the student enrollment, half went to get jobs in business and industry." "Enrollment" would not work in every application, however.

Comment: @rhetorician I was wondering if they existed a simple form that would just mean students but have a singular form. I supposed students would have an identical meaning to *student body* but loses that singular collective form.

Answer (score 1):

Would **students** suffice? As in

> Of all the students, more than half [...]

You could use adjectives or particles to cut the word to a more specific need.

Hope this helped.

PS: I believe the sentence would have to be

> The student*'s* body was found [...]

to be grammatically correct, but I understand what you mean.

Answer (score -3):

According to Oxford Living Dictionary:
enrolment
(US enrollment)
NOUN
North American
count noun 
The number of people enrolled at a school or college.
For example:
'a record enrolment of 690 students'
More example sentences

‘These changes have occurred despite the fact that student enrollments in colleges and universities are at an all-time high.’

‘Average annual wages were higher in community colleges with higher enrollments.’

‘But because of the economic downturn, college enrollments everywhere are growing.’

‘As a result of these trends, enrollments of full-time students in colleges and universities will increase by nearly 20 percent during the next decade.’

‘Rising high school and college enrollments created opportunities for both coaches and athletes.’

‘Increasing enrollments and opening new schools and colleges of pharmacy are not the only approaches to dealing with the pharmacy workforce issues that our country faces.’

‘This economic reality has boosted college enrollments despite the financial difficulties.’

‘College enrollments increased by 70 percent over pre-war levels.’

‘Across Afghanistan, schools are seeing record enrollments, with more than 4 million students in school.’

‘It is also important to realize that enrollments in community colleges are generally higher than in the past and enrollment numbers may reflect new demographics as much as anything else.’

‘The number of students with disabilities enrolled in higher education is growing rapidly, with the largest enrollments at community colleges.’

‘Nationally, minority students make up 30% of community college enrollments and more than 50% in some urban communities.’

‘Today, agricultural colleges suffer declining enrollments in technical and production fields.’

‘A year later, the college had an enrolment of 50 students, which remained constant until 1870.’

‘A sharp rise in enrollments in community colleges followed.’

‘Back in 1997, Congress passed a program of higher-education tax credits aimed at raising college enrollments.’

‘College enrollments rose, and students developed their own rules governing relationships.’

‘Due to the enlargement of college student enrollments, it becomes more and more difficult to get a job.’

‘How about falling enrollments of men in colleges, ongoing now for 10-20 years.’

‘As a result of declining enrollments, many colleges of agriculture are working to revise and/or increase recruitment efforts to more effectively attract students.

Comment: The student council is only a small subset of the student body. The student body includes all the students.

Comment: I edited the answer.